# updating constraint value not working IOS 9 Beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sendMessageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    self.messageText.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    self.messageText.delegate = self;
    self.objectImage.hidden = YES;
    self.sendImageButton.hidden = NO;
    self.imageView.hidden= NO;
    [self updateViewsHeight];

}

-(void)updateViewsHeight{
        NSLog(@"--------------------- %f -----------------------", self.view.frame.size.height);

        if (self.view.frame.size.height == 568.0){ //5s & 5
            self.textViewHeight.constant = 500.f;
            self.ImageViewHeight.constant = 10.f;
            [super updateViewConstraints];}
    }
```

This does not update the constraint. She gets the original height but I'm sure that the code inside the if is read because when I put one break in the application breaks it.

this is my properties:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageViewHeight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewHeight;
```

Comment: try `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` in the end

Comment: I try this but this not work

Comment: is it iOS 7 or iOS 8 that you are running

Comment: I guess your constraints are not set properly

Comment: I m using ios 9 Beta

Comment: I added my properties in description

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134857/3718570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what happened was an error in the IOS 9 Beta. When you delete the constants and deleted the device application the code worked. Hue

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 if (self.view.frame.size.height == 568.0){ //5s & 5
    self.textViewHeight.constant = 500.f;
    self.ImageViewHeight.constant = 10.f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```