# Update storyboard constraint using code

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have a `UIImage` in code that I would like to enlarge vertically when a button is pressed. The `UIImage` is fully constrained in the storyboard and I would like to change its height when the button is pressed.

I have linked the `UIImage` and its height constraint in the code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var botBotCons: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var botBot: UIImageView!
```

Then

```
@IBAction func testButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("testButton pressed")
    self.botBotCons.constant = 68   //or +=62 as its current constant is 6
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I get the **testButton pressed** message in the console, but the image doesn't resize. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change something in the storyboard as well?

Comment: First as a try add these lines to the end of the function               `self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`
`self.view.updateConstraints()` . If it doesnt work, may be imageView is blocked by other constraints,want see your constraints in storyboard

Comment: Thank you very much. I added those two lines of code. It didn't work. Than I went to check my constraints in the storyboard for the eleventh time and I finally found out that the top of the image was constrained to the bottom of the view by 6. I changed the constraint to be the bottom of the image to the bottom of the view, space = 0. Now everything is working. I feel ashamed. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: Do you have any other layout constraints that may get in conflict with the larger height? Are there any outputs in the console log about breaking constraints?I have set up a fresh single view application project, added an image view and a button, added constraints, dragged an outlet for the height constraints, set the constant of the height constraint in the button's action method and the height does change without any "layout" or "needed" method to be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to call `layoutIfNeeded` within the animation block. Apple actually recommends you call it once before the animation block to ensure that all pending layout operations have been completed. I just checked it with the resizing of button - everything works fine.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var btnWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!


@IBAction func resizeBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.myBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.btnHeight.constant += 50
    self.btnWidth.constant += 50

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

P.S. make sure that other constraints don't block your changes.